# How to make colorful outputs using log4net/log4j?

Tags: log4j, log4net

is there a way to display error or warning in color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, search for `ColoredConsoleAppender` on this site:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html